# Codenameone Migrating Legacy Applications to CSS

Tags: css, codenameone

I have an app made in 2018 that I want to generate a new version (with a new package and name).

The theme was made with the designer and I want to pass it to CSS. I followed the steps indicated in: "https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-legacy-applications-to-css.html", because I want to see and edit the css file (the truth is I don't handle css and this will help me much).

Unfortunately after activating the CSS file it doesn't show me an option to open said file (see figure).
[image]
I appreciate your comments.

Comment: I see a button that says "Open CSS File For Editing".

Comment: Which IDE are you using? I'm assuming NetBeans which doesn't list the CSS directory in the project view. Move to the file view where you will see the CSS directory. You can expand it and there you will see the file, etc.

If you migrate to maven this will be even simpler since then the CSS will be under the src hierarchy and will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Netbeans.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I'll detail what I've done in sections within the attached image:

1. Rename theme.res to theme_legacy.res
2. Delete indicated file and folders.
3. In the designer create the constant "theme" and save file.
4. Rename resource file in main class and save file.
5. Activate CSS file and save.

In section 6 it shows the incomplete CSS file.
After executing the project another "theme" is created as shown in section 7.
[image]
I appreciate your comments.